# Save the date: MageStackDay IV on January 15th & 16th 2016

Tags: discussion, community, event

We are back with MageStackDay #4 which is going to take place on the 15th & 16th of January 2016!

MageStackDay is an online hackathon dedicated to answering, closing and cleaning up questions on magento.stackexchange.com. The goal will be to get the answered questions rate up by at least a few percent and get more users active on this platform.

For now: Please **save the date.**

We'll be back with more information soon!

Comment: So glad this is happening again!!!

Comment: i have already book my day :)

Comment: one more thing, this time I guess our main target is magento2 related questions. so sharp your knowledge of magento2. :) Thanks Anna & Sander for organizing this beautiful event again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signup form for MageStackday IV is online!

Please register here if you are going to take part:
[MageStackday IV signup form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/10Xq23K-Ev4vN2ykWXSeaPSvZbt8zq7nkzyefgA0Bw0o/viewform?c=0&w=1)

Looking forward to your participation :-)

Comment: I  have booked my ticket again :)